# ABAddressBook does not have a member named 'removeRecord'

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

In case it helps others, I found that Apple's iOS doc is wrong in that the removeRecord method is not supported in XCode 6.1, resulting in the title error

This does not work

```
var adbk: ABAddressBook! //then assign it in some other code
var newContact: ABRecord //then create it in some other code
var success:Bool = adbk.removeRecord(newContact)   //this does not work - results in the title error
```

This is the solution to remove a record from the addressbook in Swift:

```
var adbk: ABAddressBook! //then assign it in some other code
var newContact: ABRecord //then create it in some other code
var error: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil
var success = ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(adbk, newContact, &error)
```

Incorrect Reference guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ABAddressBook/addRecord:

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution to remove a record from the addressbook in Swift:

```
var adbk: ABAddressBook! //then assign it in some other code
var newContact: ABRecord //then create it in some other code
var error: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil
var success = ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(adbk, newContact, &error)
```